# how to install xampp on ubuntu 14 without using terminal

Tags: 14.04, package-management, xampp

I am new to ubuntu.
 I am wondering is there any way to install xampp on ubuntu without using terminal and software -center. I mean can we install it using package repository for simple installation or make .sh file executable to install it simply like windows
.

Answer (score 9):

No. The creator of XAMPP only supplies a command line installer. It is a 3rd party software so if they do not offer a debian installer you will not be able to install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

The *better* option would be to install our native LAMP. It is superior to XAMPP and tailor made for Ubuntu. If you want to install the task for this the easiest method would be to copy this over to a terminal and have it execute...

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

This will install Apache, MySQL, PHP and also configure it for you. All you need to supply is a password for MySQL and you'll have a running local webserver in a manner of minutes.

> simply like windows .

Ubuntu is NOT Windows. Both have their pros and cons. One of the *cons* is the simple method of installing. *That* is what leads to all those nasty virusses and unwanted popups.

> without using terminal and software -center

Everything will need to be installed using `apt-get` either from terminal or USC. Even if you would install a debian installer from a browser it would open USC for you. We consider security an important issue.

Comment: mind sharing where things get installed, how to start stop server, place files for development?