# How to install Xampp in Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lts

I need help in installing Xampp on Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Comment: Help how to install xampp on ubuntu 14. 04LTS can not help me urgent please

Comment: read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507844/xampp-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597851/how-to-install-xampp-on-ubuntu-14-without-using-terminal)

Comment: Help how to install xampp on ubuntu 14. 04LTS can not help me urgent please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better than xampp use LAMP open a terminal an execute the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Comment: I put it as a comment: "Mejor que xampp usa LAMP abre una terminal y ejecuta lo siguiente."

Comment: Ok Joker it was for him to find it it easier please correct the and also

Comment: I understand but this is literal english speaking website and tries to preserve use of english only. You can make a notice to post it as a comment if the OP won't understand it in english.

Comment: ready and run the following then I tell how I can open a practice of php Please

Comment: @Brask then how to start `XAMPP`

Comment: The command for starting the server is:  $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Comment: lamp-server could not be found. It doesn't seem to be in the standard repositories...